# How to construct Foo<T> after receiving Foo<S>?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class `C` which is templated on `A<W>` or on `B<W>`. Now in `C`, I'd like to construct an object of type `A<U>` or `B<U>`, depending on what it was instantiated with.

If that sounds a bit strange, consider this code and the comment in it:

```
template<class W>
struct A {
  typedef A type;
};

template<class W>
struct B {
  typedef B type;
};

template<class AB>
struct C {
  // AB is A or B. If it's A we want to construct A<double>, if it's B                                                          
  // we want to construct B<double>:                                                                                            
  typedef typename AB::type type; // A or B                                                                                     
  typename type<double> D; // ERROR
  D d;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  C<A<int> > c1;
  C<B<int> > c2;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

I think `C` would need to be templated on a nested template, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, you need partial template specifications:

```
// base declaration is undefined
template< typename AorB > struct C;

// declaration for A<W>
template< typename W >
struct C< A< W > >
{
    typedef A< double > type;
};

// declaration for B<W>
template< typename W >
struct C< B< W > >
{
    typedef B< double > type;
};
```

A more general case that works for any template class with one type argument would be:

```
// base declaration is undefined
template< typename AorB > struct C;

// declaration for T<W>
template< template< typename > class T, typename W >
struct C< T< W > >
{
    typedef T< double > type;
};
```

Comment: Ah, that's what I had in mind when I said it can probably be solved using nested templates. Nice!

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by introducing a helper template which I named `translate` in the following code:

```
template<class W>
struct A {
  typedef A type;
};

template<class W>
struct B {
  typedef B type;
};

template<class AB, class U>
struct translate {
};

template<template<typename> class AB, class W, class U>
struct translate<AB<W>, U> {
  typedef AB<U> type;
};

template<class AB>
struct C {
  // AB is A or B. If it's A we want to construct A<double>, if it's B                                                          
  // we want to construct B<double>:                                                                                            
  typedef typename translate<AB, double>::type D;
  D d;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  C<A<int> > c1;
  C<B<int> > c2;
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. It does not require to modify the original class; also, using variadic templates, you can rebind any template type (not only templates with just 1 argument, like in the OP's case)

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to do it like allocators and provide a `rebind` template inside of `A` and `B`, if you have access to those:

```
template<class T>
struct A{
  template<class U>
  struct rebind{ typedef A<U> other; };
};

template<class AB>
struct C{
  typedef typename AB::template rebind<double>::other rebound_AB;
};
```

Comment: Nifty! Haven't seen that pattern before.